# Schematic interpretation, where to put resister?

Tags: power, pins, electronics, resistor

I'm new to schematics, trying to figure out where to put a resistor (no  instructions other than the schematic)

I'm told I need:
10K variable Resistor x 1, 4.7K Resistor x 1, 100 Resistor x 1

But I only see where to put the 10k resistor (I added a blue circle around the 10k). Can someone show me (describe, illustrate) where to put the others?

And where there's the triangles for +5V or AGND, do I put something there (purple circles)??

Thanks!

Here is a link from the project I'm trying to build
https://bestengineeringprojects.com/arduino-weighing-machine-using-hx711/

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 4.7kOhm resistor is shown in the second image (They simply didn't want to scramble the big image). It shows, that the pin between the resistor and the button has to be connected to pin D10 of the Arduino:

[image]

The 100 Ohm resistor isn't shown in the image, too. But in the text it says:

> Note: Cathode and Anode pin of LCD (pin 15 and pin 16) is not shown in
>   circuit diagram. Connect +5 volt to pin 15 with current limiting
>   resistor (generally 100-ohm) and pin 16 of LCD to ground.

Pins 15 and 16 are not shown in the diagram, but the text gives all necessary information. Connect pin 15 of LCD to the 100 Ohm resistor and this resistor to 5V power source. And then connect pin 16 of LCD to ground.

---

The two other symbols, that you circled, are used as indicator of the power source. Normally all pins, which are marked with +5V (triangle) are connected together to the 5V power source. The triangle consisting of 3 horizontal lines marks ground. Normally all grounds are connected together to the ground pin of the power source.

So these symbols are used, so that you don't have to draw all the lines for connecting the power lines together.

Answer (score 0):

Neither are shown in that schematic, as described in the text.

> ***Calibration Circuit:*** The weight calibration circuit is shown in figure 2. [...]
>
> [A schematic that includes a 4.7kohm resistor]

...

> Note: Cathode and Anode pin of LCD (pin 15 and pin 16) is not shown in circuit diagram. Connect +5 volt to pin 15 with current limiting resistor (generally 100-ohm) and pin 16 of LCD to ground.